# Why can't systemd reload unit files automatically?

Tags: linux, systemd

Sometimes I forget to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing some unit file, and I get a warning about it when doing `systemctl restart ***.service`.

Why it was decided to only issue a warning instead of reloading the unit automatically? (the warning happens, so change was detected and so it is possible to simply auto-reload the file).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be a specific design choice, based around race conditions and the complexity of reading the entire conf tree.

However, one approach is to use `systemctl edit`, which triggers a unit reload after it exits.

Some discussion of the issue [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790262), and [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=615527).

Comment: Yes, discussion in the linked bugs makes sense. The idea of `systemctl edit` is nice, but it creates new override instead of editing the actual file - is there a way to run it on the actual unit file?

Comment: Ah, `--full` flag does it. Well, it leads to my next question - is there a way to get list of options for some `systemctl` subcommand? `systemctl edit --help` simply prints default help list.

Comment: Best to raise that as a new question if reading the `systemctl` manpage / docs doesn't help.

Comment: @Rogach: `man systemctl | less +/"edit "` documents the options you are looking for.